# TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE - Get updated data

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I am discovering DML triggers in SQL Server. I created a trigger that registeres all inserts to one table in another table. I would like to do the same with update statement.

My INSERT Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgSuppliersLogINSERT
ON Production.Suppliers
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    insert into  [Production].SuppliersLog 
        (SupplierID,    [Action],   companynameChangedTo,   contacnameChangedTo,    contacttitleChangedTo,  addressChangedTo,   cityChangedTo,  regionChangedTo,    postalcodeChangedTo,    countryChangedTo,   phoneChangedTo, faxChangedTo)
    SELECT 
         supplierid, 'INSERT',  companyname,    contactname,    contacttitle,   address,    city,   region, postalcode, country,    phone,  fax
         FROM inserted
END
GO
```

I tried doing the same with UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgSuppliersLogINSERT
    ON Production.Suppliers
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        insert into  [Production].SuppliersLog 
            (SupplierID,    [Action],   companynameChangedTo,   contacnameChangedTo,    contacttitleChangedTo,  addressChangedTo,   cityChangedTo,  regionChangedTo,    postalcodeChangedTo,    countryChangedTo,   phoneChangedTo, faxChangedTo)
        SELECT 
             supplierid, 'UPDATE',  companyname,    contactname,    contacttitle,   address,    city,   region, postalcode, country,    phone,  fax
             FROM updated
    END
    GO
```

But as you probably know 'updated' table doesn't exist. Is there any other way to get updated data into my SuppliersLog table? Thanks.

Comment: There's Inserted for new data. And Deleted for deleted/old data

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't know that deleted table even exists. You helped me more than I actually expected ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you update a row you should use insertet table .
you can use one trigger for insert and update :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgSuppliersLogINSERT
ON Production.Suppliers
AFTER INSERT,update
AS
BEGIN
    insert into  [Production].SuppliersLog 
        (SupplierID,    [Action],   companynameChangedTo,   contacnameChangedTo,    contacttitleChangedTo,  addressChangedTo,   cityChangedTo,  regionChangedTo,    postalcodeChangedTo,    countryChangedTo,   phoneChangedTo, faxChangedTo)
    SELECT 
         supplierid, 'INSERT',  companyname,    contactname,    contacttitle,   address,    city,   region, postalcode, country,    phone,  fax
         FROM inserted
END
GO
```

if deleted (table fill after delete action) has row the action was update , but if deleted does not have any row the action was insert

```
declare @rowcount int 
, @action varchar
set @rowcount = select count(1) from deleted
if(@rowcount == 0)
set @action = 'insert'
else
@action = 'update'
```

and use select like this :

```
 SELECT 
             supplierid, @action,  companyname,    contactname,    contacttitle,   address,    city,   region, postalcode, country,    phone,  fax
             FROM inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as the previous trigger, see [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx):

> An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an insert operation; the old rows are copied to the `deleted` table first, and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the `inserted` table.

If you want to work with both the old and new values caused by an `UPDATE` then you need to join the `inserted` and `deleted` tables together.